# why does console.table not display the last entry

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

i am missing something exceedingly obvious, but it appears on my chrome browser *Version 103.0.5060.134 (Official Build) (64-bit)* the final entry is missing:

```
const objectTest = { 'one' : 'this is object one' , 'two' : 'this is object two' , 'three' : 'this is object three' } ; 
console.table (objectTest) ;     // appears to skip the final entry
console.log(objectTest.three) ;  // final entry is available
```

what must i do to get `console.table` to display the last entry?

i would like to start using `console.table` in addition to `JSON.stringify` but only if i can get it working properly.

What's even more peculiar to me is that firefox seems to work correctly.

**EDIT**:  its working fine on chrome 100-102 and chrome 104-105.  its just appears to be not working properly on chrome 103.  i tried this out on browserstack.
but again, i am assuming that i am doing something incorrect.

Comment: It is weird because that code works just fine for me. I see all three elements. Just restart your browser or computer maybe?

Comment: CodePerson71495, this just gets weirder and weirder.  what chrome are you using?  i just tried browserstack chrome,  versions 100-102 works fine, 103 does NOT work, and 104-105 works fine.  please don't tell me i found a bug in chrome?   previously, people have been executed for this.

Comment: @edwardsmarkf Yes, looks like a bug in Chrome devtools. Nobody is going to be executed for this. And as you report, it has already been fixed.

Comment: I am on chrome 103. It worked just fine for me. I am on macOS, so it just automatically hides the scrollbars until you need them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce in Chrome 103.0.5060.134:

[image]

However, as you can see, the last entry is not really missing, it's just hidden beneath that unnecessary horizontal scrollbar. If you select the text in the table, you can still copy it and also spot the selection:

[image]

The bug has already been reported at least five times:

- [Issue 1339628: console.table is missing last element in array](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1339628)
- [Issue 1340625: console.table horizontal scrollbar obscures last row](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1340625)
- [Issue 1344504: console.table does not show all properties](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1344504)
- [Issue 1346599: unnecessary scroll bars in console.table obscure content](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1346599)
- [Issue 1347572: console.table() displays a horizontal scrollbar overlaying the last table row](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1347572).

> This has been fixed and the fix will roll out soon into Stable channel.

Comment: Yea this makes a lot of sense. On macOS, the scrollbars are hidden until you hover over them.

Comment: Try opening and closing the console sidebar. This should make the scrollbar disappear.