# console.table() not showing the last element of an array

Tags: javascript, web, console

The console.table() function seems to be not printing the **last element** of the Array that generated from Map.

For example, consider this code:

```js
const data = new Map();

data.set('key0', 'value0');
data.set('key1', 'value1');
data.set('key2', 'value2');
data.set('key3', 'value3');

const dataArray = Array.from(data.entries())
console.table(dataArray)
```

Result:

[image: console screenshot]

The last entry (`key3` & `value3`) is missing from the table. Why and how do I make the console.table() prints all the entries?

Comment: This is not specific to arrays made from a Map. The same thing happens with `console.table([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73141877/why-does-console-table-not-display-the-last-entry/73155471?

Comment: That's not what I see (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMc7q.png). What's your JS environment? Mine's Chrome `103.0.5060.134` on macOS.

Comment: Mine is Brave. 1.41.100 Chromium: 103.0.5060.134 (Official Build) (64-bit) Windows 11. (Also reproducible on Edge)

Comment: Ahh. Thanks @Andy. After a closer look, the last entry is indeed hiding behind the scrollbar. Sigh.